# What's the name for the "artistic movement" /technique of these graphics?

Tags: style-identification

Can anybody help me understand if the graphics I linked have elements that make them belonging to the same artistic movement/style,and if positive which is this art name.Even if their styles look similar to my eyes I can't basically tell why.

[image: examples]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I've only ever seen this referred to as grunge. If you have Adobe Illustrator you can find a great example in your sample files.

Answer (score 4):

I'd say it's a mix of vector, grunge, and trendwhore. These works are probably from the 2004-2007 period, right after the trendwhore + 3D style was "flattened out." Here are some similar works (beaucoupzero, who made pictures 2 and 3, refers to his works as "psychedelic"):

[image: http://fav.me/d1yzgz3]
[image: http://beaucoupzero.deviantart.com/art/R-E-M-I-X-2006-30407959]
[image: http://beaucoupzero.deviantart.com/art/remix-29267499]
[image: http://fav.me/dic7eb]
[image: http://fav.me/duf6tt]

Comment: "Trendwhore"! Brilliant, I've never heard that term before but knew *exactly* what it meant the moment I saw it... I never knew what to call that stuff, I usually called it "filter-riffic"

Answer (score 3):

I would categorize this as a form of [Psychedelic Art](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Psychedelic_art). Granted, the colours are "grungy" and muted compared to most other Psychedelic Art, but the style is similar. I agree with Alan that many people would call it simply "grunge", but I think the psychedelic roots are quite evident.

Here is a link with more examples of digital Psychedelic Art. I think you'll find some examples there which show a lot of similarities:

http://psd.tutsplus.com/articles/inspiration/colorful-psychedelic-style-digital-artwork/

Comment: Hmm... Having come of age in the mid-60s, which was the heyday of psychedelic art, I have to disagree with this. Google "jimi hendrix poster" and click on the Images link. You'll get a screenful of perfect examples of what that style looks like. It feels odd to me, looking at them, that they now seem quaintly old-fashioned.

Comment: I can see many similarities between those posters and these examples in this question. Notice the rainbow and "sun rays" motif of the bottom poster, and the way the rainbow morphs into tigers. Note the collage of cityscapes, a man sitting, tigers, fire. Go through the "Features" bullet points on the wikipedia page I linked. These examples hit at least six of those eight features, and arguably all eight.

Comment: Grunge inherited from 60s pop art and psychedelic art, with a bit of help from punk, so certainly there are similarities. The psychedelic movement very clearly owes much to Van Gogh.